# error when recreating sentence

Tags: python, json, compression

So I have a program that looks at a sentence in a .txt file. The program then finds the position of each word in the sentence as well as the unique words in the sentence. These two lists are outputted in the program and then the program tries to recreate the original sentence in the .txt file based on the unique words in the sentence and position of words in the sentence, which then should be outputted in the program. The code I have so far is shown below:

```
import json
import os.path

def InputFile():
    global compfilename
    compfilename = input("Please enter an existing compressed file to be decompressed: ")

def Validation2():
    if compfilename == (""):
        print ("Nothing was entered for the filename. Please re-enter a valid filename.")
        Error()
    if os.path.exists(compfilename + ".txt") == False:
        print ("No such file exists. Please enter a valid existing file.")
        Error()

def OutputDecompressed():
    global words
    global orgsentence
    newfile = open((compfilename)+'.txt', 'r')
    saveddata = json.load(newfile)
    orgsentence = saveddata
    words = orgsentence.split(' ')
    print ("Words in the sentence: " + str(words))

def Uniquewords():
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i] not in unilist:
            unilist.append(words[i])
    print ("Unique words: " + str(unilist))

def PosText():
    global pos
    find = dict((sentence, words.index(sentence)+1) for sentence in list(words))
    pos = (list(map(lambda sentence: find [sentence], words)))
    return (pos)

def Error():
    MainCompression()

def OutputDecompressed2():
    for number in pos:
    decompression.append(orgsentence[int(number)-1])
    finalsentence = (" ".join(decompression))
    print ("Original sentence from file: " + finalsentence)

def OutputText():
    print ("The positions of the word(s) in the sentence are: " + str(pos))

def MainCompression():
    global decompression
    decompression = []
    global unilist
    unilist = []
    InputFile()
    Validation2()
    OutputDecompressed()
    Uniquewords()
    PosText()
    OutputText()
    OutputDecompressed2()

MainCompression()
```

An example test is described now. Say there is a .txt file called 'ohdear' and contains the sentence: "hello hello hello hello"

Now the program is shown below:

```
Please enter an existing compressed file to be decompressed: ohdear
Words in the sentence: ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello']
Unique words: ['hello']
The positions of the word(s) in the sentence are: [1, 1, 1, 1]
Original sentence from file: h h h h
```

As you can see, the original sentence was not recreated from the unique words and position of words in the sentence - strangely 4 h's were displayed. Can someone help with this error as I have no idea how to recreate the original sentence from just the unique words and position of words in the sentence. The problem is in the OutputDecompressed2() function. Thanks for any help in advance. I have been stuck on this for a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = orgsentence.split(' ')
```

This means that `words` is a list of strings and `orgsentence` is just one big string. But later you get:

```
orgsentence[int(number)-1]
```

Which is just going to be a character. Rather get `words[int(number)-1]`.

Also:

```
find = dict((sentence, words.index(sentence)+1) for sentence in list(words))
```

just gives you the first occurrence of each '`sentence`' since that's what `.index` does, hence you have the output:

```
The positions of the word(s) in the sentence are: [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

which is obviously wrong.

And by the way, `sentence` is a terrible variable name at that point, why not `word`?